# How to save part of the ul elements to a file using jquery

Tags: jquery

How would I go about saving part of a ul to a file. Below I mark the start and ending of this html code I would like to save to a file:

I tried this: $(ul li:first > *).clone();
But the alert displayed [object Object]
How can I see what I'm saving through an alert to verify I'm saving the right part of the ul elements?

```
          <ul id="ul_first">
              <li>a</li>
              <li>b</li>  <---- start saving at this point
              <li>c</li>
              <li>d</li>
              <li>c
                   <ul id="ul_second">
                       <li>a2</li>  
                       <li>b2</li>
                       <li>c2</li>
                       <li>d2</li>
              </ul>                 <---- end saving at this point
 </li>
```

Comment: `console.dir(yourObjectRefHere)` should do the trick

Comment: You can also use consele.log(yourObjectRefHere)

Comment: Sounds like he's using the IE developer tools to me

Answer (score 0):

Use console.log() instead of alert();

```
var selected = $('ul li:first > *').clone();
console.log(selected);
```

You can then open your [web console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.log) to view the javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use $.clone to do this.

I tried a couple of ways to do this and I think this one is the coolest:

if you are using Chrome the following will work (maybe Safari too):

> Open up your browser's web console and type this.

```
    copy($('#ul_first li:gt(0)').map(function(){
        return this.outerHTML;
        }).get().join('\r\n')) //Or if you are using Linux or a Mac, just ('\n')
```

If you are not using Chrome, the same can be accomplished in any browser's web console with:

```
     var li=$('#ul_first li:gt(0)').map(function(){
                return this.outerHTML;
              }).get().join('\r\n')
```

The title of your post indicates that you may be trying to copy this programmatically.  If you are trying to create a script that will write the above mentioned elements into an external file, the only way to do this with pure jQuery is by using the [HTML5 File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) (though this example doesn't use jQuery, only Javascript).  Without that, you would require a server side technology to write to external files (PHP, ASP, etc).